# Undefined offset on array - Get they key of each arrays

Tags: php, arrays

This is my existing code:

```
foreach($masterData as $data) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$data[0]?></td> //error line here
        </tr>

        <?
        echo '<pre>',print_r($data),'</pre>';

      }?>
```

Result when try printing the `$data`:

```
Array
(
    [payment] => Array
        (
            [name] => name
            [email] => address
            [depositdate] => 3-mar-16
            [depositamount] => 200

        )

)
1
Array
(
    [payment] => Array
        (
            [name] => John
            [email] => sample@yahoo.com
            [depositdate] => 29-Apr-16
            [depositamount] => 5000.70

        )

)
1
```

But echoing the `$data[0], [1], [2]`.. PHP give me notice:
`Notice: Undefined offset: 0`

Possible cause of this error? Anything wrong with my code and how to fix it?

Comment: USe `echo $data['payment']['name']`

Comment: what you want to echo at the place of `$data[0]`??

Comment: @Saty How I can get the array(key or index) holding the payment  arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get key of all index in array:

```
<?php 
foreach($masterData as $key=>$data) { // you can get key of array in $key
?>

<tr>
       <td><?=$key?></td> <!-- you can get $key here -->
</tr>

<?php
echo '<pre>',print_r($data),'</pre>';
}
?>
```

Comment: That was the answer I'm looking! Thank you.

Comment: @DharaParmar Thanks again. anyone could update my question.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing an offset that is undefined, just like the error message told you.

In $data you only have 'payment' as key not 0 and within you have 'name', 'email' and so on.
If you want the values of 'payment' you have to access $data['payment']

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to access your array with the key values. so just try

`$payment_name = isset($data['payment']['name']) ? $data['payment']['name'] : "";`

Answer (score -1):

you need to access your array with the key values.
so just try

```
echo $data['name'];  // or whatever element you want to retrieve from the payment-set
```

Comment: It should be `$data['payment']['name']`.

Comment: @Barmar since he is using the foreach loop $data already holds the payment array